# Почему сначала выполняется alert а потом функция со вставкой таблицы

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой код

```
async function display_list_book(){

    let res =await eel.list_book()();
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res;
}

(async function () {
    await display_list_book();
    list_copy = await document.querySelectorAll("#copy_book")
    alert(list_copy)
}());
```

почему у меня сначала выводится alert с сообщением [object NodeList].

а потом уже отрабатывает сама функция со вставкой таблицы.

Comment: Потому что асинхоронщина

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и как мне быть в этом случае?

Comment: оберни блок после функции в самомвызывающуюся анонимную асинхронную функцию и внутри сделай `await display_list_book();`  и дальше остальной код

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот так? `(async function () {
    await display_list_book();
    list_copy = document.querySelectorAll("#copy_book")
    alert(list_copy)
}());`

Comment: Выглядит правдоподобно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все равно сначало вывело пустой alert

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129907/discussion-between--and--).